# Is a piece of content posted online a "post" or a "publication"?

Tags: vocabulary

I am working on an app and I was wondering which is the most correct way to refer to a user-submitted piece of content (e.g. a "tweet" on Twitter). Is it better to refer to it as a "post" or a "publication"? And why?

Additional question, if that piece of content is tied to a geographical location (e.g. submitting content on a public map), is there a different / better way to refer to it?

Thank you.

Comment: A tweet is a 'post'. The 'publication' usually refers to the entire concern, for example a news media's title.

Comment: It's worth noting that in legal terminology, publication has distinct meanings that probably includes social media posts (and in libel/slander even to sending a private message) https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Publication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'post' would usually be an item of content submitted to a blog or social media timeline, archived by date and time, so it's the right generic word for tweets.

If content is tied to a single location, it would often be a 'point', but there are other context-specific words, such as a 'node' for an object added within the *structure* of a digital map itself.

More generic terms for content that has been submitted include 'submission' and 'entry'.

A 'publication' would normally be a greater set of data than a single user submission, such as a complete magazine, journal, book or manual.